# Can't Connect to Notion API

Tags: api, postman

I'm Uğur,

https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-database

`https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/database_id`

I used "https://www.notion.so/**111111111111111111**?v=222222222222222" as a database ID. (http://prntscr.com/22cn4dp)

I used "Authorization: Bearer $NOTION_API_KEY and Notion-Version: 2021-08-16" as a cURL.

I used it with Postman but I got an error.

Error Code:

```
{
    "object": "error",
    "status": 404,
    "code": "object_not_found",
    "message": "Could not find database with ID: 1111111111111111."
}
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notion's update has changed the location for Integration. Now you'll find it here:

Go to the database page in your workspace.
Click the ••• on the top right corner of the page.
At the bottom of the pop-up, click Add connections.
Search for and select your integration in the Search for connections... menu.
Your integration now has permission to edit the database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works, after adding the connection to my internal app, am able to get the database details

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for a few days now. The problem I had was quite simple and turns out that I just never had the workspace shared with my integration. I checked [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk7Vk_v4yfo&t=34s) at around 3 mins and only then realised that you need to share your pages and databases with the integration

Answer (score 0):

Your Notion-Version looks correct but your database id should be the content after your Notion page url i.e. https://www.notion.so/DatabaseiD. Also if you're using Postman your Authorization should be set to type 'Bearer Token' with the Notion API Key that you obtained from your integration found [here](https://www.notion.so/my-integrations).

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble getting notion to work with Zotero using the Notero plugin. I created the integration and created the database but I did not explicitly share the database with the integration. After sharing the database with the integration, Notero works perfectly.

To share the database with the integration after creating the database and integration

1. Go to the Notion page containing the database
2. Click the share button in the upper right corner of the Notion window
3. In the text box type in the name of your integration (In the picture below my integration was called "papers")
4. Select your Integration (the window should now resemble the picture below)
5. Alter a citation in Zotero to confirm that your integration works.

[image: Example of using the share button for adding an integration]

Answer (score 0):

Did Notion redesign/update that Share popup shown in the screenshot by alluppercase? I created an internal integration, but I am only seeing "add emails or people". (And when I try to connect in my react app - I get the `error - APIResponseError: Could not find database with ID`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the Notion GUI to find your Database ID is not optimal, in spite of the instructions provided.  The only reliable way to:

(1) make sure you are calling a **Database** and not a **Page**,

(2) and ensure your Integration is permitted to access the database

is to programmatically list the resources to which your integration has access, and note the IDs in the response objects marked as "Database".

Make a queryless POST request to:

https://api.notion.com/v1/search

Docs: https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-search